# How to make a variable not used out of scope?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I make this variable not used out of scope. I keep getting this error in JSFiddle: `'variable' Used out of scope`. I don't know what that means or why it occurs. I tried to fix it myself and that just made it worse. I looked all over the internet and couldn't find anything, so stack overflow was my last resort. Anyways, [here](https://jsfiddle.net/do5rhkew/) is my code. Or, If you don't prefer JSFiddle, here:

```js
var dollar = 0;
var cents = 0;

function plusOne() {
  if (cents < 95) {
    var cents = cents + 5;
    document.getElementById("amount").innerHTML = cents + " ¢";
  } else if (cents == 95) {
    var dollar = 1;
    document.getElementById("amount").innerHTML = dollar + " $";
  } else if (cents == 100) {
    var cents = 0;
    var dollar = dollar + 0.05;
    document.getElementById("amount").innerHTML = dollar + " $";
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="plusOne()">Plus five cents</button>
<p id="amount">0 ¢</p>
```

As you can see, it does not change the value at all. I don't know what is going on with it.

Comment: Var declares a *new* variable, even if it has the same name as one a level higher. So remove it from the plusOne method

Comment: you defined (with `var` or `let` or `const`)  your variables out of function - that's ok. But then you defined them again inside - that's not ok. Try to use them without `var` inside function or give them another name.

Comment: @HansKeﬆing Oh! Ha ha! I honestly didn't think that would make a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)

> The var statement declares a function-scoped or globally-scoped variable, optionally initializing it to a value.

The case here is that every time the function `plusOne` executes, you create a new variable with the name `cents` or `dollar` or `both`, whose scope is bind to the `plusOne` function.

A more optimal way to write your function, is instead of declaring a new variable, to change the value of your already existing variables.

e.g.

```
var dollar = 0;
var cents = 0;

function plusOne() {
  if (cents < 95) {
    cents = cents + 5;
    document.getElementById("amount").innerHTML = cents + " ¢";
  } else if (cents == 95) {
    dollar = 1;
    document.getElementById("amount").innerHTML = dollar + " $";
  } else if (cents == 100) {
    cents = 0;
    dollar = dollar + 0.05;
    document.getElementById("amount").innerHTML = dollar + " $";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't over declare the `var's`

```js
var dollar = 0;
var cents = 0;

function plusOne() {
  if (cents < 95) {
    cents = cents + 5;
    document.getElementById("amount").innerHTML = cents + " ¢";
  } else if (cents == 95) {
    dollar = 1;
    document.getElementById("amount").innerHTML = dollar + " $";
  } else if (cents == 100) {
    cents = 0;
    dollar = dollar + 0.05;
    document.getElementById("amount").innerHTML = dollar + " $";
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="plusOne()">Plus five cents</button>
<p id="amount">0 ¢</p>
```

Comment: This is the same as [@Konstantinos Gallis's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71002194/17935937).

Answer (score 1):

At the beginning try don't declare variables using var.
Use 'const' when you know value and this value is constans otherwise use 'let'.

```
let dollar = 0;
let cents = 0;

function plusOne() {
  if (cents < 95) {
    cents += 5;
    document.getElementById("amount").innerHTML = cents + " ¢";
  } else if (cents == 95) {
    dollar = 1;
    document.getElementById("amount").innerHTML = dollar + " $";
  } else if (cents == 100) {
    cents = 0;
    dollar =+ 0.05;
    document.getElementById("amount").innerHTML = dollar + " $";
  }
}
```